# hashes output more often in command line ftp

Tags: shell, command-line, ftp, stdout

I use a command line ftp (the one on mac osx) inside some application I developed.
The thing is, this application will be used on very slow internet connexions.

In the actual configuration, I use the stdout with hashes to determine upload progress this way:

1. I first get the exact file size.
2. I activate hash output in ftp
   3 I then simply count each time I read something from stdout how many hashes have been printed, and add them to my interal counter
   4 multiplying this hashcount by 1024 bytes, I get the transferred data over the total data to caculate percentage.

This works but isn't as fluid as I would like it to be..
The final results jumps 20-30% at a time and 'waits' for 2-3 seconds between each stdout.

on large files with a fast internet connection, let's say a 100mb file over a 50mbps connection, this is very fluid..

Is there a way to tell ftp to output the current upload state more often? like based on a time interval, every 200ms or so... ?

Comment: at any point in time, how do you know what percentage of the file has been downloaded? What clues does your ftp tool give?

Comment: @glennjackman just added to the question.